# What is this style of design called?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, interface-design

[image]

I like this style and I want tutorials to learn how to do something like this 
what should i type????

Comment: Type nothing. General graphic software user skills are needed. Write on the paper what common these cards have. Find, draw or write the same type of details and place them. Take any of those three cards. Think and you find: there's an idea that connects the items in the card. If you make your own, be sure that the idea exists. Its more than the color.

Comment: Technically these icons are pretty basic to copy in Illustrator. Look into basic Illustrator usage (shapes, strokes, fills, gradients). The hard part is to invent the designs. My advice is to go the other way around: Choose an object you want to draw in this style. Construct/draw a sketch of the icon by hand. Get inspired by (steal) details from other designs. Then try to make it in Illustrator. When you run into problems, solve those problems one at a time. If you know what to achieve and can show us what you have tried and what problems you encounter, it is much easier for us to help.

Answer (score 2):

Terms that might describe it:

- flat
- line art
- icons
- trendy

But it doesn't have a particular name. In 20 years it might be called '2010s style'. :)

They are fairly easy to create (at least in terms of mechanically). Basic tutorials for any vector illustration art should get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "style" to name.

These are just simple icons, made from a combination of lines, shapes, strokes and fills.  Just basic Illustrator stuff, and nothing complex. The bottom parts of the cards have some gradient fills.

If you are want tutorials then you probably need to search for beginner tutorials that cover using the Pen Tool, the Polygon Tool, the Rectangle and Ellipse tools,  and tutorials that cover applying strokes and fills, and gradient fills.